# python-twitter streaming api support/example

Tags: python, streaming, twitter

I was working with [python-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) and realized that twitter provides streaming [api](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api) to consume tweets in realtime. I found one example that uses pyCurl [here](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/guides/2010/04/tutorial-use-twitters-new-real-time-stream-api-in-python.ars)

Have anyone tried or know how to use that with python-twitter library? please let me know

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python-twitter doesn't support twitter's real time API.

You will have to use [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) or [Eventlet](http://eventlet.net/) to consume such a real time API.

I know not, of any existing open source libraries in Python supporting this service right now.

Comment: You don't need any of those async libraries for Twitter streaming. You can use oauth2 module to authenticate and the built in urllib module to make the HTTP requests.

Answer (score 8):

Tweepy has good modules for streaming. You can see examples [here](https://github.com/tweepy/examples).

Answer (score 6):

Check out [tweetstream](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweetstream) for a nice high-level library to access twitter's streaming API.